# Make side menu have dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I found this excellent icon based sample side menu, codepen http://codepen.io/reecegeorge/pen/JuHLq.

If you take the bottom 'Gear' icon as an example, when you hover over it displays a sub menu.  This is fine, however in a situation where you have many many items then 2 columns would be advantageous.  I modified the source (quick n' dirty) and have a new codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBQbQv.  This now adds a second column.

HTML added

```
<ul class="sidemenu-sub sidemenu-sub-sub">
    <li class="text">
       <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#secondcol1">Second column</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS added

```
.sidemenu-sub-sub {
  margin-left:  106px;
  width: 178.5px !important;
}
```

My question is, without having to completely overhaul this, is there a simple piece of CSS (or JS (can be jQuery)) which will show the second column only if needed. For example if the users window size is small the items in column 1 can automatically spill over into column 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to check the width or height and change dynamically the columns.

This will return you the width of the device screen:

```
$('body').width();
```

This will return you the height of the device screen:

```
$('body').height();
```

I think this is a good start for you to play with screen sizes.